# populate dynamically created html table in dojo and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

in html i'm dynamically creating a table:

```
function createTable() 
{
    var tablecontents = "";
    tablecontents = "<table>";
    tablecontents += "<tr>";

    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i ++)
    {
        tablecontents += "<td>";
        tablecontents += '<div data-dojo-type="com.Control" id="Control' + i + '" style="width: 143px; height: 200px;"/>' ;
        tablecontents += "</td>";
    }
        tablecontents += "</tr>";

    for(var z = 0; z < 12; z++) 
    {
        tablecontents += "<tr>";
        tablecontents += "<td>";
        tablecontents += 'C';
        tablecontents += "</td>";
        tablecontents += "<td>";
        tablecontents += '<div data-dojo-type="com.Control" id="ControlTwo' + z + '" style="width: 40px; height: 20px;"/>' ;
        tablecontents += "</td>";
        tablecontents += "<td>";
        tablecontents +=  'B'
        tablecontents += "</td>";
        tablecontents += "<td>";
        tablecontents +=  'A'
        tablecontents += "</td>";
        tablecontents += "<td>";
        tablecontents +=  '2010'
        tablecontents += "</td>";
        tablecontents += "<td>";
        tablecontents += '<div data-dojo-type="com.Control" id="ControlThree' + z + '" style="width: 40px; height: 20px;"/>' ;
        tablecontents += "</td>";
        tablecontents += "</tr>";
    }
      tablecontents += "</table>";
      document.getElementById("graphicalData").innerHTML = tablecontents;
}
```

I want to populate this table with data retrieved from a CSV file so i wrote the following code:

```
ready(function() {

            //programmatically reading CSV from external file
            var personStoreForGrid = new dojox.data.CsvStore({
                url:"datasheet.csv"
            });

            //storing to DataStore
            var objectStore = dojo.store.DataStore({
                store: personStoreForGrid
            });

            objectStore.query().then(function(results)
            {
                //results contains everything from csv file

            });

            createTable();
            parser.parse();
});
```

in this case, the table gets created before i'm able to obtain the results from the csv file. How to i reverse this so i can grab the contents just before going to create the table?

Very new to Dojo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already wrote

```
objectStore.query().then(function(results)
{
   //results contains everything from csv file

});
```

it's deferred/async action, you need to create it when it finishes query something like

```
  objectStore.query().then(lang.hitch(this, function(results)  {
  //results contains everything from csv file
    this.createTable();
 }));
```

where lang is dojo/_base/lang

Comment: this looks like it could work. but actually all i did was re-arrange my code and included all my code that actually populates the table into the ready(function() ... this solved the problem. thanks anyway!